# Proof for factorials (rising and falling)

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

I have to prove something with falling and rising factorials.

Falling factorials are defined as
$$(n)^{\underline{k}} = n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1) $$  and rising factorials are defined as$$(n)^{\overline{k}}=n(n+1)\cdots(n+k-1).$$

> Show
> $$(n+m)^{\underline{k}}= \sum_{v=0}^\infty { k \choose v}\cdot {(m)^{\underline{k-v}}} \cdot (n)^{\underline{v}}.$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: i tried to translate the different parts into falling factorials

Comment: My first step would be to write it completely with full factorials.  The rising and falling factorials can be represented as ratios of factorials, as can the combination symbol.  I think you will find the same terms appearing.

Comment: can you please show me a start?

Comment: As an aside, your expression has a typo.  That should be a $\binom{k}{v}$, not a $\binom{v}{k}$... that is, unless you happen to be from a part of the world that actually uses $\binom{r}{n}$ to denote the number of $r$-element subsets of an $n$-element set...  You would be in an extremely small minority if so

Comment: youre right. i dont know if i did it wrong or the editor after that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proof via [Double Counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(proof_technique)), i.e. a "Combinatorial Proof":

Imagine $n$ red and $m$ green balls, all uniquely labeled.

The LHS of your expression counts the number of ways to arrange $k$ of these in a line (*without repetition*), arriving at the expression having combined the red and green piles to form one larger $(n+m)$-sized pile to choose from.

The RHS of your expression counts the same, except we still kept the piles separate and broke into cases based on how many of the balls appearing in our $k$ were red, noting that for $v$ red balls we pick which $v$ of the positions were used for the red balls, arranging $v$ red balls into those positions, and arranging $k-v$ green balls into the remaining positions.

As they both correctly count the same scenario, the expressions must be equal.

Comment: ok i will try that way soon and come back

Comment: "*try that way*"... this is already a full proof.