# Showing $(n+m)^{\underline{k}}=\sum_{v=0}^\infty{k\choose v}\cdot{(m)^{\underline{k-v}}}\cdot(n)^{\underline{v}}$ for falling factorials

Tags: summation, proof-writing, binomial-coefficients, factorial, products

Falling and rising factorials are defined as
$$
\color{blue}{n^{\underline{k}}}=\,\,\color{blue}{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n-j)} \qquad\qquad
\color{blue}{n^{\overline{k}}}=\,\,\color{blue}{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n+j)}
$$

> Show
> $$(n+m)^{\underline{k}}= \sum_{v=0}^\infty { k \choose v}\cdot {(m)^{\underline{k-v}}} \cdot (n)^{\underline{v}}$$

Maybe inductive proof? please no combinatoric proof

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof for factorials (rising and falling)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4119698/proof-for-factorials-rising-and-falling)

Comment: yes its the same question i think but the comment there isnt useful for me because im not allowed to do it combinatoric

Comment: You may state that explicitly in your question before someone takes his/her time to provide you with a combinatorial proof.

Comment: ? maybe he (the other user) could use the combinatorial proof under his question?? and now everyone could read it here. i am very thankful for every help here but why are so many people here so unfriendly?

Comment: I meant that you could add a sentence to your question saying that you are not allowed to use a combinatorial argument, so nobody will try to give you that type of an answer.

Comment: ok i did but i dont think someone helps me hahha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that$$n^{\underline{k}}=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n-j) = k! {n \choose k} $$
and ${k \choose v} =0$ for $v >k$.
So we have to prove
$$k!{n+m \choose k} = \sum_{v=0}^{k}{k \choose v}(k-v)!{m \choose k-v}v!{n \choose v}$$ $$=\sum_{v=0}^{k} k! {m \choose k-v}{n \choose v} $$
That is, we have to show$$ {n+m \choose k} = \sum_{v=0}^{k} {m \choose k-v}{n \choose v} \tag{1}$$
The LHS of $(1)$ is the coefficient of $x^k$ in $(1+x)^{m+n}$ and the RHS is the coefficient of $x^k$ in $(1+x)^m(1+x)^n$, so they are indeed equal and $(1)$ holds.

Comment: and why is that equation after your "Note that"? why is it k!(n k)?

Comment: @kurlya $k!{n \choose k} = k! \cdot\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} = \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n-j)$

Comment: @Andre.J: Nice to reveal Vandermonde in disguise. (+1)